# Asterisk how to detect out of service and mailbox

Tags: asterisk, voip

In my context, I need to detect different call status in Asterisk, including out of service (e.g., phone is turned off) and the phone is directed to voice mailbox.

However, there are no such statues correspondingly in call [DIALSTATUS](https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+variable+DIALSTATUS). Why does it happen? Is there a walk-around?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have read about extensions states and hints

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Extension+State+and+Hints

Also you may check SIPPEER function which have info about current sip peer state.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Function_SIPPEER

Answer (score 0):

Also see the DEVICE_STATE function: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Function_DEVICE_STATE